# Как бороться с многовкладочностью в вебе?

Tags: веб-программирование, java-ee

Пользователь может пооткрывать кучу одинаковых вкладок, запутаться, поработать сначала в одной, потом в другой, потом вернуться к третей, и ни в одной из них данные не будут актуальные и будет происходить полная анархия на сервере. Как с подобными проблемами борются в веб разработке, подскажите, гуру.

Answer (score 1):

Существует несколько методов. Допустим на вот это вкладке, генерировать pulling на сервер, чтобы каждая вкладка, знала, сколько вкладок ещё открыто, и если их много, спросить пользователя, надо ли закрывать эту вкладку. Можно записывать в куки число открытых вкладок, если больше одной, тупо отвечать на запрос все кроме 200 ответа. Можно задавать после одного клика по ссылке с вкладкой, вопрос «а надо ли новая вкладка?».